# Trigger Event (css position fixed - sticky header/navigation) upon scrolling past specific point

Tags: jquery, scroll, css-position

I am looking to replicate what Google+ does with their large cover photo on user profile page. It is large to start and as you scroll past a certain point, the header (cover photo and tab navigation) changes to position:fixed and sticks. You can scroll back up and the photo enlarges again. Other websites have been implementing this as well with their navigation (i.e. Techcrunch). I actually don't even need the complication of show / hiding / animating a div that looks a bit different once it sticks, I just need to get the position to fix.

I've found other posts on it, but none of my attempts work. I will note that I am not using the browser window to scroll, but an internal div... so not sure if that could be what I'm screwing up.

edit* updated with new approach based on comment provided. Still not perfect though. The newly fixed area does not allow scrolling. Additionally, the area that remains scrollable "jumps" when the areas above stick (assumably because they were all floated and now the previously floated divs are missing / fixed. I tried adding a margin-top to the body section to counteract this, but doesn't work.

Anyway, here is the following jQuery and jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/md3DV/43/

```
$('#contentMain').scroll(function(){

    if ($('#contentMain').scrollTop() > 255) {

        $(this).children('#mainInfoProfileContainer').addClass('stick');

        $(this).children('#mainNavContainerProfile').addClass('stick');

        $(this).children('#body').addClass('stick');

    }

    else {

        $(this).children('#mainInfoProfileContainer').removeClass('stick');

        $(this).children('#mainNavContainerProfile').removeClass('stick');

        $(this).children('#body').removeClass('stick');

    }

});
```

edit* Also, there is an issue I have that I cannot replicate in the fiddle. When I scroll to the specific spot the div jumps back and forth, refusing to get fixed... it's like there are two conflicting events happening. However, it doesn't happen with the same code in the fiddle...

Comment: if $('#contentMain').scrollTop() > 255px)  should be if ($('#contentMain').scrollTop() > 255px)

Comment: Also, 255px should probably be in quotes.

Comment: I've realized that the rest of my code on this page including this code doesn't work with this there. It looks like there is an error in my code, but not sure where. I included your fix but still not working. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: also look at your if statement: if ( $('#contentMain').scrollTop() > 255) {}

Comment: Still not working. :(

Comment: Your fiddle isn't including jQuery as dependency. Check the drop down on the left.

Comment: Check the spelling on your "#mainInfoProfileContainer" .. In CSS is says contain(t)er. Have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/md3DV/26/
Not all of your solution, but a hell of a lot closer. You can't scroll on the yellow or green though. But hopefully it gets you going.

Comment: @Daniel is correct. Here's an updated fiddle : [http://jsfiddle.net/md3DV/31/](http://jsfiddle.net/md3DV/31/). Still buggy, but it's progress for sure..

Comment: Ah, @Daniel that's much closer than mine. OP have a look at [this page](http://www.proust.com/story/tom/timeline) which does what you ask. I wrote the code for that attach/detach bar a year or two ago, don't remember what I did, looking into it now..

Comment: @couzzi - that looks pretty sweet. Like the effect with the arrow showing the scroll position.

Comment: I agree, that is pretty cool. I dug into the source code and it seems you added a class to change position. I like that solution more so tried implementing it. I got it to more or less work. However, encountering same problem as above in regards to no scrolling over fixed areas. Also, the body section jumps when above divs become fixed.

Comment: Had a look, looks like my `scroll` event is on the `$(window)`, instead of a `<div>` with `overflow:scroll-y`. Maybe try giving that a shot?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need it to be on a div, not using the browser scroll for this...